# Can't kill service that is started from another service

Tags: java, android, android-service

My application has a service which spawns another (different) service using `this.startService(intent)`.

Let's call them service 1 and service 2.

After service 1 starts service 2, it kills itself using `stopSelf()`.  From what I can surmise this happens succesfully.

Service 2 then performs a task after which I call stopSelf() on it, but the service continues operating.

I haven't found any other question on this particular topic.

Comment: "but the service continues operating" -- how have you determined this? Bear in mind that you need to clean up your own stuff in the service's `onDestroy()`, such as any threads that you forked.

Comment: Yeah I think my issue was that I wasn't removing 2 views (screen overlays) that were added by the service, so the service was hanging around.  After implementing code to remove the views things seem to be working fine.